# Python selenium select option from dropdown

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, select, selenium-chromedriver, html-select

I am trying to select an option from  **http://www.lacoteargus.ma/cote-maroc/recherche/**

But I am getting this error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated`  
in this line 
`Brands.select_by_visible_text('BMW')`

Here is my script:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
import time

Email = '***************'
Pass = '******'
LoginUrl = 'http://www.lacoteargus.ma/'

chrome_options = Options()
chromedriver_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, options=chrome_options)

driver.get(LoginUrl)
driver.find_element_by_name('strLogin').send_keys(Email)
driver.find_element_by_name('strPwd').send_keys(Pass)
driver.find_element_by_id('validation').click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('caret').click()
time.sleep(1)

Brands = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('marque'))
Brands.select_by_visible_text('BMW')
```

I have also tried:
`Brands.select_by_value('1')` 
 and  
`Brands.select_by_index('1')`
 None of them are working.

Comment: [What is the correct way to select an <option> using Selenium's Python WebDriver](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/2258)

Comment: Its a select2 or similar element, not a simple select element. If you query //[text()='BMW'] you will see two elements (the first is the hidden option and the second is the span that you want to click to trigger the select).

Comment: I suggest that you don't use the time.sleep, its not recommended and you will spend to much time were you don't want to.
See WebDriverWait() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a select element, the select element is hidden.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os

Email = '*****************'
Pass = '******'
LoginUrl = 'http://www.lacoteargus.ma/'

chrome_options = Options()
chromedriver_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, options=chrome_options)

driver.get(LoginUrl)
driver.find_element_by_name('strLogin').send_keys(Email)
el = driver.find_element_by_name('strPwd')
el.send_keys(Pass)
el.submit()

driver.find_element_by_class_name('caret').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[text()='BMW']").click()
```

Comment: Awesome @filipe you are genius. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you seen the date field below? can I select 2010 January? @filipe

Comment: Added another response for that question.

Answer (score 1):

About how to select a date on the bootstrap date picker:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "datemec")))
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='datemec']/parent::div/span")
el.click()

n = 0
while True:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'datepicker-years')]//th[contains(@class,'prev')]").click()
    el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='input-group-addon']")
    try:
        el.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[text()='2000']").click()
        break
    except Exception as e:
        if n > 3:
            raise
        n += 1
```

Comment: Thanks, Man! It's working like a charm. Thank you so much. @filipe